# How to implement ResignFirst Responder for keyboard in UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dismiss keyboard on touch anywhere outside UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274119/dismiss-keyboard-on-touch-anywhere-outside-uitextfield)

I am using UIScrollView in my app. I am putting few text fields and button. I want to hide my keyboard when they touch outside of the textbox. (I mean they will be taping on the uiscrollview). I have tried a lot of things... I use UIGestureRecognizer but its not working... help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution just tried and it works.. Hope helps

Add the following code to your viewDidLoad;

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    //create a tapGesture which calls a removeKeyboard method
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(removeKeyboard)];

    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    [self.yourScrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

-(void)removeKeyboard {
    [self.yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Hope helps....

Comment: Thanks you sir... you are a saviour..

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code in your view...

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([yourTextView isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != yourTextView) {
        [yourTextView resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not working... i copied the code and tried it with my text box. But its not working. Instead of yourTextView, I used my textFieldName.

Comment: your code has [touch view], but I am using UIScrollview that covers the entire UIView

Comment: Is your view set up to be the delegate of your UITextField?

Comment: I set scrollview.delegate = self; Is this right way to set the scrollview as delegate? Or should I change it to view instead? How can i set UIView as my delegate?

Comment: Your TextField(s) need the delegate setting to the Files Owner (the view). You can do this in Interface Builder by dragging delegate to "Files Owner" like in this screenshot. http://cl.ly/image/3v2D0q0u1r0T

Comment: i changed it but its still not working. My text box is in UIScrollView. Not the UIView. My UIScrollView Covers the UIView Completely... UIView is behind UIScrollView... So I can tap only the scrollview

Comment: That should work fine re: ScrollView, also ensure you have <UITextFieldDelegate> added to your .h file.